# React.js function not being called on component event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, scope

I'm new to React.js and maybe this question is kinda vague, please be kind. I am using [react-image-gallery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-gallery) to create a gallery in my component. This gallery component has a prop of callback function `onImageLoad` which is called when an image is loaded (i am using lazy-loading). The problem is that this `onImageLoad` prop is able to do direct `console.log('called')` but it doesn't fire any event. So this works:

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageGallery onImageLoad={console.log('called')} />
    )
  }
}
```

But these don't work:

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  EVENTNAME = e => {
    console.log('called', e);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageGallery onImageLoad={this.EVENTNAME.bind(this)} />
    )
  }
}
```

This doesn't work either:

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  EVENTNAME = e => {
    console.log('called', e);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageGallery onImageLoad={e => this.EVENTNAME} />
    )
  }
}
```

Nor this one:

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  EVENTNAME = e => {
    console.log('called', e);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageGallery onImageLoad={e => console.log('called', e)} />
    )
  }
}
```

have tried this too:

```
class Post extends React.Component {
      EVENTNAME = e => {
        console.log('called', e);
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <ImageGallery onImageLoad={this.EVENTNAME} />
        )
      }
    }
```

I'm guessing this is a problem of function scoping and something like that. Some hints and guidance will be appreciated. Thanks!

> View Full File Code [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-cherry-iz8pq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: I suggest you move the `EVENTNAME` declaration outside the `render` method and call it like `this. EVENTNAME` instead of `this.EVENTNAME.bind(this)`. Arrow functions uses lexical `this` so we don't have to bind them

Comment: @Fiju have tried that, not working. I have updated the question. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

are you getting error like ,'EVENTNAME' is not defined        no-undef
if that's the case,
add declaration in front of function definition.

```
 let EVENTNAME = e => {
          console.log('called', e);
        }
```

Comment: Hi, no I'm not getting any sort of error. It's just not calling any function. and yes I have tried declaring the function through a variable, lamentably, it ain't working.

Comment: yeah probably. you may want to see the full code of my file. check here: https://codesandbox.io/s/small-cherry-iz8pq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: it actually getting called onImageLoad.. what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]  Problem solved define your images as

```
import React from "react";
import ImageGallery from "react-image-gallery";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      slidesLoaded: 0
    };
  }

  images = [
    {
      original: "https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1000/600/",
      thumbnail: "https://picsum.photos/id/1018/250/150/"
    },
    {
      original: "https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1000/600/",
      thumbnail: "https://picsum.photos/id/1015/250/150/"
    },
    {
      original: "https://picsum.photos/id/1019/1000/600/",
      thumbnail: "https://picsum.photos/id/1019/250/150/"
    }
  ];

  checkAndShowSlider = e => {
    console.log("called", e);
    let count = this.images.length;
    let nowLoaded = this.state.slidesLoaded + 1;
    if (nowLoaded === count) {
      document.querySelector(".images.section").css("display", "block");
    }
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        slidesLoaded: nowLoaded
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ImageGallery
          onImageLoad={e => this.checkAndShowSlider(e)}
          items={this.images}
          showPlayButton={false}
          thumbnailPosition="left"
          useBrowserFullscreen={false}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: let me know if you have any query

Comment: Hi Prakash, thanks for the reply. I just tried that, it ain't working for me. would you like to see the full code of my file?

Comment: <ImageGallery onImageLoad={e => this.EVENTNAME(e)} items={images} />

Comment: you can pass your event as argument to your function  like : this.EVENTNAME(e)

Comment: yeah, I just tried that after seeing your answer. it's not working for me.

Comment: make sure your function is outside of render

Comment: i have updated answer.you have to pass your images to items otherwise your onImageLoad not going to called

Comment: yes i have tried that prakash, you may want to see the full code which i have tried here: https://codesandbox.io/s/small-cherry-iz8pq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: the function is not being called, you see `console.log("called", e);` is the very first line of the function. but there's nothing in the console.

Comment: i can log here : called 
SyntheticEvent {dispatchConfig: null, _targetInst: null, _dispatchListeners: null, _dispatchInstances: null, nativeEvent: null…}

Comment: now that's weird because I don't see any logs here on my side: [see](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eitlzwu5iqg15mv/Snipaste_2020-01-30_10-52-09.png?dl=0)

Comment: refresh your page

Comment: done that. also tried on all browsers (chrome, edge chromium, firefox) none of them logs anything.

Comment: are you sure you have define your images on top of checkAndShowSlider function ??

Comment: I am checking on the code sandbox you provided. even that doesn't log anything.